# Arduino Uno R3 error

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an arduino uno R3. I am able to upload the programs with no connectivity issues. But there is a problem while executing the program and I don't know what that is. The 13th pin led is not blinking as the default bootloader program comes with preloaded blink program. I am not able to reset the board too. What might be causing the problem?

I even tried to reload the bootloader program. But the same think happens yet again.

Thanks in advance and Regards,
Rishi.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to blink one led with pin 2 or 3 ( any of the digital pins ). You might have a working Arduino uno but your led on the board can be broken.

Otherwise,you should try to flash the bootloader with a secondary arduino and check if you get the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with the other pins. It is not working. Actually after the done uploading message in the IDE, I get an additional message that "avrdude() not in sync"